# Error while adding pagecontroller view in the view of other Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I tried adding pageViewController itself to a view in a controller by storyboard instantiate but produces following error code

- ViewController

  ```
  func instantiate(){

      let pageController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing:PageViewController.self)) as! PageViewController

      addChild(pageController)
      pageController.didMove(toParent: self)
      pageController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      contentView.addSubview(pageController) // error Cannot convert value of type 'PageViewController' to expected argument type 'UIView'

      let views:[String:Any] = ["pageView":pageController.view]
      contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[pageView]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
      contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[pageView]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
  }
  ```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'PageViewController' to expected argument type 'UIView'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PageController inherits from UIViewController. What you're doing is adding the same as a view. That is why you're getting an error as the argument is not UIView.

Rather than adding pageviewcontroller, add the view embedded in it. Change the line to `contentView.addSubview(pageController.view)`

Comment: @pedestrian Can you please elaborate more on this. I have to add the pageViewController in the view of another controller

Comment: rather than adding pageviewcontroller, add the view embedded in it. Change the line to  contentView.addSubview(pageController.view)

Comment: @pedestrain now its working but after the third scroll it is not stopping . It goes to first instead of stopping

Comment: @Swamy check the delegate methods of UIPageViewController. Inside viewControllerAfterViewController method, you must be returning the first  ViewController there